# Installing default templates in visual studio

Tags: windows-xp, installation, visual-studio

How do I install default templates in Visual Studio 2005 ? 
 Whenever I start Visual Studio 2005
and click on File -> New Project it shows me shows me this message.

[image]

and then there are no templates in the New Project dialog box.

[image]

I have found the template folder at

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio
>   8\Common7\IDE\VSTA\ItemTemplates

The main problem is I can't reinstall Visual Studio as I don't have Admin Rights on my college PC. And my teachers won't re-install it as .Net is in the next module.

So is there any way to install default templates ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best solution would be to either reinstall Visual Studio, or at least reset the settings by running `devenv.exe /ResetSetttings` from the Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt.  However, both of those actions will require that you have administrator privileges.  So, to work around this, try these steps(note: I've only got VS 2008, but the steps should be similar):

1. Open the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE` folder in Windows Explorer
2. Copy the `ItemTemplates` and `ProjectTemplates` directories to your `%HOMEPATH%\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Templates` directory.
3. Open Visual Studio

If that doesn't work, please follow the instructions in the first screenshot and post what information you can see in the Event Viewer.